# getView() crashes in getDrawable()

Tags: android, crash, android-inflate, getview

I get many weird reports of app crashes (using app compat library) when OS calls the getView() of one of my adapter. It crashes in getDrawable() with ResourceNotFoundException under Android 4.x or RuntimeException under Android 5.x or UnsupportedOperationException under Android 6.x. The getView() is actually calling inflate() with a mostly simple layout file.

The call stack is always like this:

```
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java)
at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:3756)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init> (LinearLayout.java)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init> (LinearLayout.java)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init> (LinearLayout.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java)
at my_app.activity$adapter.getView
```

Here is the layout files that 'cause' this on Android 4.x and 5.x:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark"/>
```

The only drawable used in that layout is available in hdpi, mdpi and xhdpi. How come Android cannot find it? By the way, I can't reproduce this in emulator or an actual device running 4.x or 5.x!

Any suggestions will be appreciated, Those are my top 4 app crashes representing more than 90% of those!

I used to have background set to @null and changed it to #00000000 to no avail. Also included the drawable in theme's attributes and having src="?menu_overflow" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Is this drawable file is .xml file?

Comment: It's a simple png file.

Comment: Did you try adding `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi` versions of the drawable? Better yet try adding a generic version of the drawable.

Comment: In last update (yesterday), I've added a generic drawable, however I can already see 3 reports on Android 5.0, none on 4.x so far. Need more time I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark"
```

instead of

```
  android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark" // in your image button
```

**Update**

Dont forget to use android's `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton` instead of `ImageButton` (this wont crash ).

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#00000000"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark"/>
```

Comment: If I do this, the button no longer shows any drawable.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, as far as I can tell the issue has disappeared so it might actually work pretty well. Thanks.